# Google rich snippets not showing on testing tool but showing on search?

Tags: seo, schema.org, rdfa, rich-snippets

If you type in "Boyce Avenue" on Google, it shows a rich snippet of their upcoming events which I'm assuming is using [Event Information](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=164506). However, if you type in "boyceavenue.com/tour.html" in Google's [rich snippet tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=boyceavenue.com/tour.html&view=), nothing shows up. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195211/rich-snippets-in-google-results/9295243#9295243) in your other question.

Answer (score 0):

Google and other search engines are using various data sources for generating Rich Snippets and similar functions. Rich meta-data crawled from the pages, be it RDFa, microdata, or microformats, is only ONE (yet important) source.

Google seems to have bilateral agreements with -- typically large -- sites for consuming their structured data directly. This why you may see rich snippets on pages that have no data markup in the HTML.

Google Fusion Tables (http://www.google.com/fusiontables/Home/) may also become a technique for exposing structured data to Google.

However, in general, using schema.org or http://purl.org/goodrelations/ (for ecommerce) markup in RDFa or microdata syntax is IMO the best option for new sites,

1. because the data will be accessible to search engines and browser extensions alike and
2. because the data will also send relevance signals to search engines (see http://wiki.goodrelations-vocabulary.org/GoodRelations_for_Semantic_SEO for more details.

Best wishes

Martin Hepp