# Rich snippets in Google results

Tags: html, seo, rich-snippets

I am looking to include rich snippets into a site I'm building to reflect a musician's upcoming tour schedule. I have done some searching on various musicians and have found a few which seem to follow a similar format. I have uploaded two screen shots below to show as an example of what I mean exactly.

Example 1:

[image]

Example 2:

[image]

What is puzzling me is the fact that when I enter these sites into [Google's Rich Snippet Test Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets), no data shows up. Furthermore, when I check the source for one of the [tour pages](http://boyceavenue.com/tour.html), there are no rich snippets incorporated into the code. How are these sites managing to get their tour dates listed in this format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct, these band pages are not implementing rich snippets of any form. What Google is actually doing is showing information pulled from other sites about that band. This information comes from the sites listed on the "More Info" line. These 3rd party sites are the ones implementing rich snippets into their pages.

I don't have enough rep to comment on Oded's "answer" to this question, but he is completely wrong. Microformats are an accepted form of rich snippet markup, just like microdata and RDFa. I would recommend going with Schema.org microdata on your site, though, since Google is presenting it as the future of rich snippet markup

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I noticed that, in the source, there was no implementation of any rich formats including Microformats which was puzzling me even more. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

As Johnathon mentioned, the future really belongs to microdata format, because it's the part of the new HTML5. I highly recommend to use this format. 
I believe that this is the even rich snippet, which have you showed in your post. You can implement your event rich snippet like this:

```
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Event">
  ​<a href="http://www.example.com/events/spinaltap" itemprop="url" >
    <span itemprop="summary">Spinal Tap</span>
  </a>
   <img itemprop="photo" src="spinal_tap.jpg" />

  <span itemprop="description">After their highly-publicized search for a new drummer,
   Spinal Tap kicks off their latest comeback tour with a San
   Francisco show.</span>

  When:
  <time itemprop="startDate" datetime="2015-10-15T19:00-08:00">Oct 15, 7:00PM</time>—
  <time itemprop="endDate" datetime="2015-10-15T19:00-08:00">Oct 15, 9:00PM</time>

  Where:
  ​<span itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/​Organization">
     ​<span itemprop="name">Warfield Theatre</span>
     ​<span itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Address">
         <span itemprop="street-address">982 Market St</span>, 
         <span itemprop="locality">San Francisco</span>, 
         <span itemprop="region">CA</span>
     </span>
     <span itemprop="geo" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/​Geo">
        <meta itemprop="latitude" content="37.774929" />
        <meta itemprop="longitude" content="-122.419416" />
     </span>
  </span>

  Category: <span itemprop="eventType">Concert</span>
  <span itemprop="ticketAggregate" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Offer-aggregate"> 
    Tickets from $<span itemprop="lowPrice">10.00</span>-$<span itemprop="highPrice">11.00</span>
    <span itemprop="currency" content="USD" /> 
    <span itemprop="offerCount">2,000</span> tickets available
    <a href="http://www.example.com/events/spinaltap/alltickets" itemprop="offerurl">
      http://google.com/ticket</span>See all available tickets</a>
  </span>
  <span itemprop="tickets" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Offer"> 
    <a href="http://www.example.com/events/spinaltap/presale" itemprop="offerurl">Presale tickets</a> 
    <span itemprop="price">$10</span><span itemprop="currency" content="USD" /> 
      till <time itemprop="priceValidUntil" datetime="2015-11-10">10 November 2015</time> 
      (<span itemprop="quantity">1000</span> available)  
  </span> 
  <span itemprop="tickets" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Offer"> 
    <a href="http://www.example.com/events/spinaltap/tickets" itemprop="offerurl">Full-price tickets</a> 
    <span itemprop="price">$11</span><span itemprop="currency" content="USD" /> 
  </span>
</div>
```

If you still having problems, then take a look at this Google article http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=164506&topic=1088474&ctx=topic.
To know more about rich snippets, what are they, what are they useful for and what type of rich snippets exist, check my article at http://blog.victorlava.com/what-is-a-rich-snippet-everything/.

Answer (score 0):

I also agree that Google not only fetches and displays rich snippet data from the owner website or the querying website, but it also uses third party data to pull the result into the rich snippet friendly search result links.

Recently, Google has been pushing a lot of data using its Knowledge Graph and updated search algorithms. However it depends on many factors to see your site's data into Google search result using the rich snippet format. Factors like your site's authority, popularity, content trustworthy generally play vital role and that's what happening with the above example case.

Thanks